# Django iterate over check boxes

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Trying to dynamically create a list of checkboxes that when selected will perform an action. I have the checkboxes created as expected, and I have an action working as expected. I can't seem to get a hold of the correct box(s) to perform the action on. For example, when I click the third box, or the second and third box the action is always performed on the first box. I have verified that the POST data is correctly passing the checked boxes prefix's and form name's, but somehow I am telling the code that if a box is checked, perform the action on the first instance rather than on the checked box or boxes. Here is what I have:

forms.py

```
class remove_resource(forms.Form):
    active = forms.BooleanField(label_suffix='', label='', required=False)
```

views.py

```
def edit_project_resource (request, offset):
list_resources = Allocation.objects.filter(project_id=offset).filter(active=True).order_by('user_id').distinct('user_id')


display = {}
for r in list_resources:
    check = remove_resource(prefix = r.pk)
    display[r.user_id] = (check, r.user_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        check = remove_resource(request.POST, prefix = r.pk)
        if check.is_valid():
            if request.POST.get(check, True):
                Allocation.objects.filter(project_id=offset).filter(user_id = r.user_id).update(active=False)

                return HttpResponseRedirect('/project_profile/%s/' % offset)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue was in checking the POST dictionary. Here is what that line changed to and it now works.

```
if request.POST.get("%s-%s" % (r.pk, 'active')):
```

Best I can tell, this is basically looking for a value in the post dictionary and because I am adding the prefix for each checkbox, I need to return a search query of 'prefix-active' where prefix was r.pk and active was the form name.

Please correct this answer if I am not describing how this works correctly.